# Error "return type int is not compatible with Intent" when using FirebaseMessagingService class

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging

I need FCM service in my application, I can't use FirebaseMessagingService class,  it says :

```
Error:(24, 8) error: zzaa(Intent) in FirebaseMessagingService cannot override zzaa(Intent) in zzb return type int is not compatible with Intent
```

here is my code

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {
  @Override
  public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    sendNotification(remoteMessage.getData().get("message"));
  }

  private void sendNotification(String messageBody) {
    //
  }
}
```

I'm using this version of library **`compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.2.0'`**

[image]

Comment: Having same problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved my problem, I was using the latest version of google map and auth services

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.4.0'
```

when I downgrade version to **9.2.0** problem were solved

Answer (score 7):

I fixed this same problem in my case by changing this:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:9.4.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.2.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.2.1'
```

To:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:9.2.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.2.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.2.0'
```

Just make all this version are same.

Answer (score 5):

Try running all services with the same version. In this case change

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.0.2'
```

to

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.2.0
```

and see if the same issue happens.

Comment: I'm using latest version :/

Answer (score 2):

Why would you downgrade? It's better to bump the 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging' version to match the play-services version (9.4.0 in your case) and you are ready to go.

So `compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.4.0'` will do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup

Please use the latest google-services plugin and firebase version.

If getting a "Could not find" error, please make sure you have the latest Google Repository in the Android SDK manager.